# Dicom Multiframe Player

Tags: java, image, jpeg, dicom

i am working on a making a Multiframe DICOM player in java and here is the code that i have used:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageInputStream;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


import org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReaderSpi;

public class DicomMultiframePlayer extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel fileLabel;
    private JTextField fileField;
    private JButton btnChoose;
    private JButton btnPlay;
    private JButton btnPause;
    private JButton btnStop;
    private JButton btnExit;    
    private Vector<BufferedImage> images;
    private ImagePanel imagePanel;  
    private boolean stop;
    private int currentFrame;

    public DicomMultiframePlayer() {
        super("DICOM Multiframe Player using dcm4che - by samucs-dev");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        images = new Vector<BufferedImage>();
        imagePanel = new ImagePanel();

        fileLabel = new JLabel("File:");
        fileField = new JTextField(30);
        btnChoose = this.createJButton(25, 25, "...");

        btnPlay = this.createJButton(80,25,"Play");
        btnPause = this.createJButton(80,25,"Pause");
        btnStop = this.createJButton(80,25,"Stop");     
        btnExit = this.createJButton(80,25,"Exit");
        btnStop.setEnabled(false);

        JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel();
        panelNorth.add(fileLabel);
        panelNorth.add(fileField);
        panelNorth.add(btnChoose);

        JPanel panelSouth = new JPanel();
        panelSouth.add(btnPlay);
        panelSouth.add(btnPause);
        panelSouth.add(btnStop);
        panelSouth.add(btnExit);

        this.getContentPane().add(panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().add(panelSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if (!btnPlay.isEnabled()) {             
                if (stop) break;                
                currentFrame++;
                if (currentFrame == images.size())
                    currentFrame = 0;
                imagePanel.setImage(images.get(currentFrame));              
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(70);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
        if (e.getSource().equals(btnChoose)) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int action = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            switch(action) {
                case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
                    this.openFile(chooser.getSelectedFile());
                    break;
                case JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION:
                    return;
            }
        }       
        if (e.getSource().equals(btnPlay)) {
            btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
            btnPause.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            stop = false;
            new Thread(this).start();           
        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(btnPause)) {
            btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
            btnPause.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            stop = false;
        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(btnStop)) {
            btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
            btnPause.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);
            stop = true;
            currentFrame = 0;
            imagePanel.setImage(images.get(0));         
        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(btnExit)) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private JButton createJButton(int width, int height, String text) {
        JButton b = new JButton(text);
        b.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        b.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        b.addActionListener(this);
        return b;
    }

    private void openFile(File file) {
        images.clear();
        try {
            System.out.println("Reading DICOM image...");           
            ImageReader reader = new DicomImageReaderSpi().createReaderInstance();
            FileImageInputStream input = new FileImageInputStream(file);
            reader.setInput(input);         
            int numFrames = reader.getNumImages(true);
            System.out.println("DICOM image has "+ numFrames +" frames...");            
            System.out.println("Extracting frames...");
            for (int i=0; i < numFrames; i++) {
                BufferedImage img = reader.read(i);
                images.add(img);
                System.out.println(" > Frame "+ (i+1));
            }           
            System.out.println("Finished.");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            imagePanel.setImage(null);
            return;
        }
        stop = false;
        currentFrame = 0;
        imagePanel.setImage(images.get(0));
    }

    private class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private BufferedImage image;
        public ImagePanel() {
            super();
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024,1024));
            this.setBackground(Color.black);            
        }
        public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
            this.updateUI();
        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            if (this.image != null) {
                g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DicomMultiframePlayer();
    }

}
```

and here is the error that i am receiving:

```
org.dcm4che2.data.ConfigurationError: No Image Reader of class com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KImageReaderCodecLib available for format:jpeg2000
    at org.dcm4che2.imageio.ImageReaderFactory.getReaderForTransferSyntax(ImageReaderFactory.java:99)
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.initCompressedImageReader(DicomImageReader.java:352)
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.initImageReader(DicomImageReader.java:337)
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.read(DicomImageReader.java:530)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at dcm4chee.DicomMultiframePlayer.openFile(DicomMultiframePlayer.java:155)
    at dcm4chee.DicomMultiframePlayer.actionPerformed(DicomMultiframePlayer.java:103)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

any solutions or help regarding what i am missing or what i should so differently 
Thank you

Comment: You don't have that JPEG2000 library plugin on your classpath at runtime.

Comment: @chrylis can you provide the procedure to do that

Comment: Can you try different images other than JPEG2000?

Comment: @AlexT. i am only providing a .dcm file as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the JAI libraries. There are instructions on the dcm4che site for installing these.

Unfortunately JAI is no longer being maintained. I believe the folks at dcm4che have forked the source from java.net and are attempting to provide at least some bug fixes.

http://www.dcm4che.org/docs/reference/dcm4chee/html/dcm4chee-installation.html